# Занести ответ(значения) из БД в пременную

Tags: python, sql

Здравствуйте! Скажите, можно ли как-то поместить ответ(значения) из БД в переменную? То есть, у меня есть такой запрос:

```
try:
x.execute("""(SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`)
                FROM cocktail
                WHERE (`component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier')
                GROUP BY `component_id`
                ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 2)
        UNION ALL
            (SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`)
                FROM cocktail
                WHERE (`component_typeName`<>'alkohol' AND `component_typeName`<>'likier')
                GROUP BY `component_id`
                ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 3)""")
conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    conn.rollback()
    conn.close()
```

Ответ из БД я получаю вот такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, получается три поля, могу я как-то строка за строкой внести это все в переменную и потом обращаться к данным? То есть как-нибудь вот так:

```
назвние id количесвто
водка 1 40
виски 2 15
джин 3 10
commponent[0][name][id][num] = водка 1 40
copmnent[0][name] = водка
```

Надеюсь, я все понятно описал.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить результат из объекта [курсора](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) (в вашем случае это x) можно с помощью метода fetchall

```
result = x.fetchall()
```

В результате в переменной result получите список из кортежей примерно такого вида:

```
[(5, водка, 78), (52, джин, 64), ...]
```